# How do I plot $1-\phi(4.65-z/2)$?

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a [power function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power) in *Mathematica*, namely $1-\phi(4.65-z/2)$. This can be written as

```
Int[1/sqrt[2\Pi]*exp(-x^2/2),x,-\infty,4.65-z/2]
```

But I cannot seem to get this to plot. Can someone explain how to plot this?

Comment: The syntax contains numerous errors.

Comment: How should I modify it?

Comment: Search the docs, all the functions you need are very easy to find.

Comment: Also, look at the documentation for `Erf`.

Comment: Specifically, look at Exp, Sqrt, and Integrate, and note that Mathematica is case sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Φ[x_] := CDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x]

Plot[1 - Φ[4.65 - z/2], {z, 0, 16}]
```

[image]